# Why Sending Email From PHP-Mailer is Slow

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, swiftmailer

I am using PHP-Mailer.
its working fine but its send email very slow.
like some time its took one sec to send email.but mostly it took more then 2 min or more some time it took 30 min.
is there is any alternative email sending method.
or any way to send mail in 3 sec or 10 sec.

```
$mail->Timeout  = 36000;
$mail->Subject = "Registration";
$mail->From = "info@educatorguru.com";
$mail->FromName = "Educatorguru.com";
$mail->AddReplyTo( "info@educatorguru.com" );
$mail->AddAddress( $email );
$mail->Body =$message2;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: looks server problem, the code is tooo simple for that issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PHPMailer wiki has [an article on maximising performance when sending in volume](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists), but similar measures help single messages too.

With the code you posted, it means you're sending using PHP's `mail()` function, which uses a sendmail binary to open a synchronous SMTP connection to localhost - you can help debug what's actually holding things up by adding this to your script:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
```

This will produce lots of debug output with timestamps, so you'll be able to see what part is slow.

The alternative is not to send interactively - store your messages in a 'to do' list/queue and get a cron job or other process to pick up messages and send them asynchronously - this will mean that your pages can return instantly without having to wait for the message to send.

Answer (score 1):

its because my hosting server is slow that's why its send slow email.
now i change my hosting server .
now its working  absolutely fine thanks every one